# If you multiply the smallest positive floating point value by a non-zero number, are you guaranteed a non-zero result?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

If I take `epsilon` to be the smallest positive non-zero floating point number (be it `16`, `32`, or `64` bit) and multiply `epsilon` by a non-zero floating point value of the same size:

> Am I guaranteed a *non-zero result* of the *same sign* as the original
>   value? Or do I risk rounding error (zero, or switching signs)?

Environment: Python/Numpy

Comment: Imagine that you multiply the smallest positive floating point number by itself. The number is < 1, so the result must be even smaller in magnitude. We have a contradiction, so the hypothesis does not hold.

Comment: You could risk either rounding error or chopping error where rounding is completed as expected (toward the nearest value above or below a set point).  chopping is completed always toward zero.  Which would you expect to use?  Under which circumstances would you think you might actually switch signs by constant reduction?  Zero should be the ultimate limit because of the multiplication...

Comment: All excellent points, and obvious in hindsight. Could I add to this the clarification then: what floating point value would it take to guarantee a non-zero value?

Comment: An infinity.  Because 754 supports "denormalized" numbers, the exponent range of finite representable floats is not symmetric:  no matter how big a positive finite float you start with, there are representable finite floats of the same width substantially smaller than its reciprocal (where "substantially" means "enough smaller to force underflow to 0 when multiplied by the original").

Comment: Another excellent point which makes perfect sense. Ok, for posterity then, how about we define the two smallest values which can be multiplied such that a non-zero result is produced. That seems like it would tidy up the loose ends. And would multiplying *any* two values greater than this value guarantee a non-zero result?

Comment: Except there are many such pairs, and you haven't defined what "smallest" means for a pair of floats ;-)  The most obvious example is to use `sqrt(epsilon)` for both.  Then their product is the non-zero `epsilon`.

Comment: As to "multiplying _any_ two values greater than this value guarantee a non-zero result?", 754 multiplication is monotonic, so basically yes.  There's no guarantee you'll always get a _finite_ result, though.

Comment: @TimPeters: You don't actually need an infinity. For example, multiplying 1 by any positive float will never produce 0. The smallest float that works is the next float after 0.5, which is just enough that if you multiply it by the smallest positive float, the result rounds away from 0.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you!  I stand corrected :-)

Comment: I made the same mistake you did at first before realizing that the asymmetry of the exponent range only guarantees you can get a result less than 1, not that you can force an underflow.

Comment: Smallest depends on the datatype, for float32, simple experimentation tells me that the smallest value you can square and not round to zero is between 1e-23 and 1e-24. Knowing that rounding error is monotonic (from comments) I can then say with certainty that if I multiply a non-zero float32 that is >1e-23 by 1e-23, I will get a non-zero result. Though technically there's a slightly smaller number than 1e-23 that works, though for my purposes this is actually sufficiently close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.nextafter(0, 1)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 4.9406564584124654e-324

In [4]: x*x
Out[4]: 0.0
```

When the exact result is between 0 and the smallest positive float, it has to round to one of those options, and in this case, 0 is closer.

If for some reason you want to customize this behavior, NumPy lets you customize the behavior of underflow and other IEEE 754 floating-point exceptions with [`numpy.seterr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html), although it won't affect operations on ordinary Python objects:

```
In [5]: numpy.seterr(under='raise')
Out[5]: {'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}

In [6]: x # NumPy float, not regular float, despite its looks
Out[6]: 4.9406564584124654e-324

In [7]: x*x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a3ff2a28c75d> in <module>()
----> 1 x*x

FloatingPointError: underflow encountered in double_scalars

In [8]: (4.9406564584124654e-324)**2 # regular float
Out[8]: 0.0
```

There's no way to change the rounding mode.

Comment: And `x*-x=-0.0`

Answer (score 11):

Of course not, and epsilon has little to do with it.  For example,

```
>>> x = 1e-200
>>> x
1e-200
```

is far from epsilon, but

```
>>> x * x
0.0
```

underflows to 0.  If we actually used epsilon instead, then, e.g., multiplying it by 0.25 would underflow to 0 too.

Provided your platform C compiler and hardware support the 754 standard, though, the sign of the zero would match the sign of the multiplicand:

```
>>> x * -x
-0.0
```